How do strokes work? [svg - optimization]
I am pretty new into this whole svg-topic and i am learning how to optimize svg's. Here is an example for an optimization:
Old Vector graphic:


<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  fill="black" stroke="none">
  <path d="M 24,39.51A 2.29,2.29 43.71 0 1 22.24,37.9L 7.67,9.73A 1.56,1.56 105.76 0 1 8.25,7.68 1.56,1.56 19.93 0 1 10.4,8.46L 24,34.74 37.66,8.35a 1.53,1.53 162.36 0 1 2.06,-0.65c 0.72,0.37 0.99,1.29 0.61,2.04 -5.08,9.9 -9.84,19.02 -14.98,28.93 -0.25,0.48 -0.89,0.86 -1.43,0.84z"/>
</svg>



New Vector graphic:


<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
  <path d="M 9,9 24,38 39,9"/>
</svg>



PS: Lets say they look the same.
My logic tells me, that a stroke is much much better for line-graphs than fill, because you take less points. I can say i optimized a 380B file into  189B (~ 50%), with the same quality.
Now my question is, if i make the svg bigger in my browser they stay the same, but in figma... If i resize the graph a) (380B) vertically and horizontally the width of the line adapts to the resize (that makes sense because of the points), but if i resize the graph b) (189B), the width stays the same, it wont get smaller or bigger. As you can see, i did not add vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke". Why isn't there a mathematical calculation for resize like, i have set the width to 2, it should calculate like 2 for 32x32, and if its 128x128 => the width sould be 8
Sorry if my question seems to be dumb, maybe its the only case in figma, idk.
I tried to expect, that the stroke-width scales up

It looks like implementation flaw in figma. Stroke width is part of the image and should scale with it.

@VasilyLiaskovsky It means Figma has an Issue there? So the optimization i did is correct? I have seen a lot of designers, who work with fills instead of strokes, but why? Is there some positive affects? (If we only think about lines) Whats the best practice?

Answer by @Vasily Liaskovsky,
There is a mistake (or they did not consider it) in the flaw of Figma. The width of the Stroke is not locked to the size of the graphic. That's why we can scale the graphic, but the width doesn't scale with it. They should add an Feature like a lock symbol on the right of the stroke-settings, that is as standard chosen. So if we re-scale the graph, the width re-scales to.
Question has been answered, that's why i am closing it.

fill and stroke are 2 diferent drawstyles.
fill fills (everything between the stroked outline) and stroke draws the outline
And you have to set the stroke-width attribute yourself.
As seen when you set a red stroke on your first SVG. I set stroke-width=2


<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  fill="black" stroke="red" stroke-width="2">
  <path d="M 24,39.51A 2.29,2.29 43.71 0 1 22.24,37.9L 7.67,9.73A 1.56,1.56 105.76 0 1 8.25,7.68 1.56,1.56 19.93 0 1 10.4,8.46L 24,34.74 37.66,8.35a 1.53,1.53 162.36 0 1 2.06,-0.65c 0.72,0.37 0.99,1.29 0.61,2.04 -5.08,9.9 -9.84,19.02 -14.98,28.93 -0.25,0.48 -0.89,0.86 -1.43,0.84z"/>
</svg>



SVG (single) path editor
Copy the d-path into the site https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/# and it may get a bit clearer


Thanks for your answer, i should change the title of my question, as it is misunderstood. @Vasily Liaskovsky already answered my question. Its an mistake in the flaw of figma, because they don't lock the width of the stroke according to the height x width.
